# Can I modify jquery/javascript on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I installed a theme that has some desc wrapping effects of some images (when you pass by the image with the mouse cursor, it will slide or something) which is made probably with javascript/jquery?
Is it possibly to deactivate this effect without losing the settings on the next update of my theme? I have created a child theme which I use to edit the css of my website, but I don't know how should approch jquery/javascript.

ps. I really can't give you link to the website because it is put on private, but I will try to provide more info if you need to help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance,
G

Answer (score 0):

In your themes folder, there should be a `/js` or `/scripts` directory. The JavaScript/jQuery on your page should be contained within that.

The full path of your theme from the root directory will be `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME`. Within this folder you will find the JavaScript folder.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer Tania. Will I lose the newly saved settings after I update my WP theme next time?

Comment: If you're using a child theme, your styles will override the WP theme. If you're modifying the core, your changes will *not* be saved, and the update will override what you have changed.